# Possible to establish an *exclusive* Remote Desktop session to bypass FLEX?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, flex

Remote Desktop sessions are by default not exclusive--they're shared. So multiple users can log into the same box.

This is causing problems for me, as I am trying to access software that connects to a FLEX license server. FLEX won't allow connections through RD. See here for more info: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka4063.html

VNC is not an option as it looks like port 5900 is blocked. Is there any way to get Remote Desktop and FLEX to play nice?

Answer (score 1):

Are you connecting to a server or workstation? RDS sessions allow multiple users to simultaneously log on (to an RDS server, not a workstation) but nothing running within those individual sessions is "shared".

Your problem is not with RDS, it's with the Flex license type that you have. Why not purchase the appropriate license type or deploy the current software/license on a supported OS?

Answer (score 0):

Likely even if you were to make the RDP session "exclusive" you would still be stuck, as the software will still detect that you're running on an RDP (terminal services) connection.

What about something like [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com)?